Avoiding recursion errors
I'm trying to solve a certain problem recursively, and I'm having trouble with the proper usage of recursion in Mathematica. Note, I'm fairly now in Mathematica but have experience with other languages such as Python.
The main idea is having a background parameter $\lambda$ that controls some behaviour of the function f. This function f gives rise to a certain function g that is calculated through f. The function f is now updated through g, and so on.
(I think) I need two indices. The first index moves in the list of $\lambda$ values, and the second one moves in the number of iterations done for each of the $\lambda$ values. The While will be later inside a For loop that regulates the $\lambda$ values.
ClearAll[f, g];

parameterArray = {1, 1.5};
plots = {};

c = 0.5;

(* the -1 index symbolizes a converged solution for the previous \[Lambda] value, to state the base case *)
g[1, -1, x_] := 0 ;
f[1, -1, x_] := -parameterArray[[1]] (x - 1/2) + g[1, -1, x];

n = 0;
m = Length[parameterArray];

While[n <= 5,
  
  If[n == 0,
   f[m, 0, x_] :=(-parameterArray[[m]] (x - 1/2) + 
       g[m - 1, -1, z]);,
   f[m, n, x_] := (-parameterArray[[m]] (x - 1/2) + g[m, n - 1, x]);
   ];
  g[ m, n, x_] := - c ^(n + 1) Sin[f[m, n, x]];  
  n++;
  ];

This code works without error as long as I'm not calling any functions. In fact, if can look up the final definition of either functions f[m, n-1, x] or g[m, n-1, x] (n-1 since the n++ is at the end of the While loop,)  but only after the loop.
If I try anything else i.e. call either of the functions inside the loop (that of course I will do since I need to work with them,) I will get a recursion error, but I fail to see why.
Another thing I have tried is, instead of defining the functions f, g for each value m, n, defining them globally, in the following way
ClearAll[f, g];

c = 0.2;
parameterArray = {1, 1.5};
plots = {};

g[1, -1, x_] := 0 ;
f[1, -1, x_] := -parameterArray[[1]] (x - 1/2) + g[1, -1, x];

f[m_, 0, x_] :=(*c f[m-1,  -1, 
  z]+ *)(1 - c) (-parameterArray[[m]] (z - 1/2) + g[m - 1, -1, x]);
f[m_, n_, x_] :=(*c f[m,  n-1, 
  z]+ *)(1 - c) (-parameterArray[[m]] (z - 1/2) + g[m, n - 1, x]);

n = 0;
m = Length[parameterArray];

While[n <= 5,
  
  g[ m, n, x_] := - c ^(n + 1) Sin[f[m, n, x]];
  n++;
  ];

But of course with no results (otherwise I wouldn't be writing this).
Edit: So I noticed that when defining each function for specific values of m,n  (e.g. f[m,3,x_] := f[m,2,x_] +3) I don't get an error, but something like n=3; f[m,n,x_] := f[m,n-1,x_] +3 is problematic. I can showcase this in the following script
ClearAll[f, g];

nPoints = 200;
xArray = Array[# &, nPoints, {0, 1}];

c = 0.;
parameterArray = {1, 1.5};
plots = {};

n = 0;
m = Length[parameterArray];
\[Lambda] = parameterArray[[m]];
g[x_] := 0 ;


f[1, -1, x_] := -parameterArray[[1]] (x - 1/2) + g[x];
f[m, 0, x_] := -parameterArray[[m]] (x - 1/2);


While[n <= 3,
  Print[f[m, 0, 1]];
  \[Rho] = 
   Interpolation[{xArray, 
      ArcTan[\[Lambda]]*Sin[2 \[Pi] xArray]* f[m, n, xArray]} // 
     Transpose];
  n++;
  Print["n=", n, ", ", f[m, n, 1]];
  
  f[m, n, x_] := 
   f[m, n, x] - parameterArray[[m]] (x - 1/2) - 
    Derivative[-2][\[Rho]][x];
  ];

But if instead of indexing the iterations with n I just do them by hand I get something that works.
ClearAll[f, g];

nPoints = 200;
xArray = Array[# &, nPoints, {0, 1}];

c = 0.;
parameterArray = {1, 1.5};
plots = {};

n = 0;
m = Length[parameterArray];
\[Lambda] = parameterArray[[m]];
g[x_] := 0 ;


f[1, -1, x_] := -parameterArray[[1]] (x - 1/2) + g[x];
f[m, 0, x_] :=-parameterArray[[m]] (x - 1/2);
Print[f[m, 0, 1]];
\[Rho] = Interpolation[{xArray, 
     ArcTan[\[Lambda]]*Sin[2 \[Pi] xArray]* f[m, 0, xArray]} // 
    Transpose];
n++;
Print[n];
f[m, 1, x_] := 
  f[m, 0, x] - parameterArray[[m]] (x - 1/2) - 
   Derivative[-2][\[Rho]][x];
Print[f[m, 0, 1], f[m, 1, 1]];
\[Rho] = Interpolation[{xArray, 
     ArcTan[\[Lambda]]*Sin[2 \[Pi] xArray]* f[m, 1, xArray]} // 
    Transpose];
n++;
Print[n];
f[m, 2, x_] := 
  f[m, 1, x] - parameterArray[[m]] (x - 1/2) - 
   Derivative[-2][\[Rho]][x];

Print[f[m, 1, 1], f[m, 2, 1]];
\[Rho] = Interpolation[{xArray, 
     ArcTan[\[Lambda]]*Sin[2 \[Pi] xArray]* f[m, 2 , xArray]} // 
    Transpose];
n++;
Print[n];
f[m, 3, x_] := 
  f[m, 2, x] - parameterArray[[m]] (x - 1/2) - 
   Derivative[-2][\[Rho]][x];

I changed the code a bit so that it reflects a little bit better the way I expect the code in the attempt to solving this problem to work.
I don't understand Mathematica, I feel it's extremely petty. What's the difference of just writing 3 or doing n=3; n?

Your definitions depend on undefined global variables n and m. E.g.: g[2, 0, x_] := -c^(n + 1) Sin[f[m, n, x]]

They are defined just before the While loop. Moving those definitions to the beginning of the script changes nothing.

Try e.g. g[2,0,1]  and you get -0.0078125 Sin[f[2, 6, 1]]
